# Python matplotlib was not plotting for all the 3 options available

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the ARIMA model, but I have 3 SKU but I'm getting only One plot after the loop got executed. Please help

```
for sku in sku_list:
    print()
    print(sku)
    df_sku = df[df['Product SKU'].isin([sku])]
    period_index = 0
    y = df_sku.Sales
    model = ARIMA(y, order=(2, 1, 0))
    results_ARIMA = model.fit(disp=-1)  
    plt.plot(y)
    plt.plot(results_ARIMA.fittedvalues, color='red')
    plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ARIMA.fittedvalues-y)**2))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: plt.show is a blocking statement; push it outside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try changing the indentation and create different sets of data? Your loop seems to return only one value.

```
y=[]
results_ARIMA=[]
for sku in sku_list:
    print()
    print(sku)
    df_sku = df[df['Product SKU'].isin([sku])]
    period_index = 0
    y.append(df_sku.Sales)
    model = ARIMA(y, order=(2, 1, 0))
    results_ARIMA.append(model.fit(disp=-1).fittedvalues)
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(results_ARIMA, color='red')
plt.title('RSS: %.4f'% sum((results_ARIMA-y)**2))
plt.show()
```